# StreamWriter object not using provided absolute path

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, streamwriter

I have code as follows:

```
Dim writer As New StreamWriter("S:\folder\text.txt") 'S: is a mapped drive to a share on our server
```

When this code runs I get the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The given path's format is not supported.

So I tried this instead:

```
Dim writer As New StreamWriter("\\server\share\folder\text.txt")
```

Whenever this code gets ran I get the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'S:\projectfolder\project\bin\Debug\‪\ server\share\folder\text.txt'.

It seems that the program is trying to use the path I provide as a relative path when I am quite sure that either `S:\...` or `\\server\...` should be an absolute path. I have used this code in other programs successfully so it is very confusing.

Comment: Is the code running under a user account which has that drive mapping?

Comment: Yes, the account the code is running on has the drive mapped.

Comment: Not using Option Strict On in this code. Changing it would mean updating numerous other parts so I elected to create a new project to test with Option Strict On. I still get the same exception. IO.Directory.GetDirectories("S:\") successfully return the directories.

Comment: The actual file is called "cgrlist.txt". Shift-right-click -> Copy as Path returned the same path name when I pasted into the code. Originally, I went into the properties of the text file, into the security tab, and copied the object name and pasted into the code.

Comment: IO.Directory.GetFiles("S:\folder\", "*.txt") returns an array with the expected file. Trying locally to "C:\Temp\cgrlist.txt" works. The entire path is about 30-40 characters in length. I have correct permissions to write to this location on our server though, so I do not expect it to be a security issue.

Comment: It will not create a FileStream either. Tried with "S:\..." and "\\server\share\...").

Comment: Can you open the file in a text editor, like Notepad?

Comment: I can manually create, delete, and edit the text file with a text editor.

Comment: How about making a new directory on the server to try it in?

Comment: Using another directory on the same server works.

Comment: Does the path which leads to a non-working file contain any of these: AUX, CON, NUL, PRN, COM0 COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT0, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, LPT9 ?

Comment: The path does not contain any of those strings. However, my supervisor changed the assembly name and now it seems to work. I do not think this is a solution, more of a work-around, but it would save you time from having to help me.

Comment: That's bizarre, but glad you got it working :)

Comment: Thank you for all of your help @AndrewMorton

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation. This hint led me to the solution. If the path contains a name that is the same as the application it will be interpreted as a relative path. Changing the folder name fixed it for me.